# Tangent Circles, and Two Parallel Lines

Tags: geometry

I have been looking at the following problem.

[image]

We are given the radii of the two circles, and need to find the radius of the third one. Now what I know is that we can connect the center points of the circles to form a triangle. I have also created a rectangle above that. All I need to do is to create an equation for r for which we can solve.

Here is my current work:

[image]

Perhaps the equation will have something to do with the upper long and lower long side. If someone could help me with the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, take the time to tag carefully you questions. Read the descriptions of the ones you used and [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4547483/edit) them accordingly.

Comment: Excellent work.  You're very close.

Comment: The top circle has radius $4$, but it looks like you took its radius as $9$.

Comment: Hello Paul, Yes, it was supposed to be 9. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks already very good. Try Pythagoras on the narrow triangles on the right:

\begin{align*}
BE^2+CE^2&=BC^2\\
\left(2\sqrt r\right)^2 +
\bigl((r-9)+(r-16)\bigr)^2 &=
(9+16)^2 \\
4r + 4r^2 - 100r + 625 &= 625 \\
4(r-24)r &= 0
\end{align*}

So there is one degenerate solution of $r=0$ (for which I can't find any geometric intuition off then top of my head) and one solution of $r=24$.

The key ingredient here that isn't labelled in your diagram is that length $BC$ is the sum of the radii of the two small circles of known radius, since it's a line segment connecting the centers of touching circles.

Note that I've assumed the radius of the smallest circle to be $9$ in line with the labels in your diagram, not $4$ as stated in the problem statement diagram.